# Install Windows 7 on SSD while retaining Ubuntu dual boot on HDD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I have just bought a 120GB SSD for my computer. I currently run a 1TB HDD with a Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 dual boot. I want to install Windows 7 on my new SSD (rather than cloning and migrating, which I think will just get messy because I have 3 partitions: 1 only for Windows, 1 for my documents and settings, etc., and 1 for Ubuntu.)

My aim is to reserve the HDD for Windows Documents, Music, Videos, etc. and Ubuntu. I want to minimize writing to the SSD as much as possible, but it will mean wiping the HDD and resizing the disk to create larger partitions for both Documents and Ubuntu.

I haven't been able to find anything specific to what I'm looking for and need advice on how to create a new dual boot system.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much the same as your previous configuration. The easy way to do this is to install Windows to the blank SSD without the hard drive connected, then plug the hard drive back in, create your windows partition, then install Ubuntu, selecting to install on the free space of the hard drive.

Comment: Hah, seems so simple! I presume it's then just a matter of copying over backed up Ubuntu files and programs from the external hd?